# Black bar in beetween the image when Background move infinite

Tags: 2d, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to scroll my background forever and so I'm using the background image twice. When the first one goes off screen, it should relocate to the end of the second one. However, there seems to be a black bar in between the two images and so it seems that the image is not being moved into place quick enough. What would be the algorithm to do such a thing to give the illusion of a continuous background? I've got this at the moment.i use this line of code for moving the background

```
>  for 1st sprite poistion 

    >     sprite->setPosition(Vec2(0,0));
        sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));

    for 2st sprite poistion 

    > sprite2->setPosition(Vec2(sprite->boundingBox().size.width -10, 0));
        sprite2->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));


    void HelloWorld::sprite_move(){
    > sprite->setPosition( Vec2(sprite->getPosition().x-1, sprite->getPosition().y));
        sprite2->setPosition( Vec2(sprite2->getPosition().x-1, sprite2->getPosition().y));

        if( sprite->getPosition().x <-sprite->boundingBox().size.width){
            sprite->setPosition( Vec2( sprite2->getPosition().x + sprite2->boundingBox().size.width, sprite->getPosition().y));
        }
        if( sprite2->getPosition().x <-sprite2->boundingBox().size.width){
            sprite2->setPosition( Vec2( sprite->getPosition().x + sprite->boundingBox().size.width, sprite2->getPosition().y));
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of the issue would improve the question!

Comment: May I ask why you re-junked your code? We have to scroll now. And is it really specific to iOS?

Comment: but using the scrollview, can i scroll infinite??